# Untrusted SSL not working in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: cordova, ssl, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, sencha-touch

I developed a Sencha Touch app for Windows Phone, packaged using Cordova. It makes call to Server APIs which has an untrusted SSL installed.

The App was working fine till Windows Phone 8.0, but after upgrading to Windows Phone 8.1, call to Server APIs fail with status-code 0.

Is there something that IE is restricting untrusted ssl calls in Windows Phone 8.1, and was not restricting in Windows Phone 8.0?

Answer (score 0):

WebView in WP8.1 never allows you to go to an untrusted site.  I don't know if this was the case in WP8.0 WebBrowser.  You will have to manually install the untrusted certificate to make this work.